# What is an affine change of variables?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, linear-transformations, transformation

Affine transformation I have come across before, but never affine change of variables? In a proof I'm trying to understand it is state that we can just make an "affine change of variables" to conclude the general result from the specific one.

Anyone?

Comment: For a single variable, $x\to ax+b$

Comment: @seht111  If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a synonymous for **a linear change of variable**.

That is a change of variables in the form:

> $$\vec x'=A\vec x+ \vec c$$

**EG for n=2**

$$\begin{cases}x'=ax+by+c\\y'=dx+ey+f\end{cases}$$

where $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are given constants.